# Installing SSL on server TrustStore - Cielo?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cpanel, truststore

Hi I am using a server with cPanel, and I want to instal the SSL of Cielo on my TrustedStore, the Cielo gives us 3 archives .crt and I don't know how to do that.

If somebody helps, me I will be grateful.

If you need more information, please ask =D

Answer (score 0):

Hello **SSL Installation on Cpanel is Easy one**

Kindly follow The Guidance which has Screenshots too.
[Installing a SSL certificate on your server, using cPanel](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9418//installing-a-ssl-certificate-on-your-server-using-cpanel)

If you have WHM access watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ezgd1bDiko

Hope now you Can install the SSL..  Good luck.

Comment: when try to instal a sign SSL says that don't correspond to my domain.

Comment: auto signed SSL by Cielo, is this that a I wanna install

Comment: So do you purchased the SSL? for your domain? or Self Signed Cert?
and

Self signed certs wont work with Cpanel..

If it says error that didnt correspond to the domain whether you entered the domain name wrongly? while generating that ssl>.

or
You need to Contact the cert provider..

Comment: yes we used a purchased SSL , so Cielo told me that it is different Cielo SSL and Comodo SSL (that it is ours) and I have to install the Cielo certificated on Trusted certificate repository

Comment: Im little confused in your last reply.
You got COMODO SSL cert? 
Cielo ssl i heared 1st time.(is that Free or paid? Do you have any link to that?)

and Have you installed it? SSL requires dedicated ip Do you have that?

If it says that ssl didnt correspond to the domain 
Im Sure you need contact the ssl provider because that mean the Issue is with provider we can do anything due to auto generated.

or if you are willing to use Different Provider i can suggest you a Different Provider.

Comment: Cielo it is a "bank" or better it is a gateway, so I am trying to use the gateway of Cielo to receive the payment. But for that, I have to use the plugin of Cielo, and for this I have to install their certification. It is 3 archive .crt to instal in my server, on trustedstore, they call - "the repository of trusted certificates"  , I have  a dedicated server , I have too the Comodo SSL.

Comment: I have centOs and cPanel in my server

Comment: So have you successfully installed the Comodo ssl on your server?

for the Cielo crt you may ask them to install it for you.. i think the issue from the Cielo side.

Comment: Yes, I have successfully installed Comodo ssl! Cielo is not responsible for the installation = /, they just say "install and we do not support!"

Comment: I am in contact with my server to resolve that! because I already have one ssl so to install another it is more difficult than normal!

Comment: If you have idea to Change your Control panel? migrate to Plesk Onyx
That is simply awesome with advance feature which Cpanel didn't Offers.. I used cpanel last 7yrs from last Year i started to use Plesk Onyx there is Letsencyrpt extension which offers you free Standard SSL the most trusted free service Comparing cpanel with Plesk onyx .. Plesk license is very cheap comparing cpanel, and Free SSL and They support nginx and apache combine. So this is my advice.. If you want you may migrate.

Comment: thanks Ajmal for that, but we need to use the cPanel until the end of the year, so thanks a lot for trying to help me!

Comment: I guess the error is because we are using one ssl , and we need to "instal" another, we use the COMODO and we need to install the .crt from Cielo, and when I try the convencional way the button "installation" appear disable, so I have to try to install in another way!

Comment: Okay give a try Plesk Onyx, Next year..

Good luck..
Thank you Daniel.. ;)